# Unknown column in 'where clause', but its actually a value

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me nuts, I cant see the error for the life of me...

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `data_specs` WHERE `Item_Code` = `ACR102190250`
```

And I get this error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'ACR102190250' in 'where clause'
```

But its not a column, its a value...

Comment: use single or double qoutes

Comment: You used backticks instead of quotes in the query.

Comment: Instead of confusing myself with backsticks and quotes I'd rather just use none and only quotes when using text: `SELECT * FROM data_specs WHERE Item_Code = 'ACR102190250'`

Comment: to elaborate a little bit, the `\`` (backtick) denotes an identifer (schema, table, column etc.) which is why mysql thinks your value is a column - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the backtick (`) from the value and use single quotes(')

```
SELECT * FROM `data_specs` WHERE `Item_Code` = 'ACR102190250'
```

Comment: It always was clear to **me** but one should always explain what has changed to ensure **future** users with similar issue understand as well. Also, I didn't downvote, I was the upvote after your change.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for your suggestion, I'll keep this in mind and from the next time I'll post all my answer with required explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `data_specs` WHERE `Item_Code` = 'ACR102190250';
```

To Asssign the values,you have to use ('')  **Single Quote**. But in your query you have used **backquote** (`)

Answer (score -1):

First of all check the spelling of your column is it correct or not.

**First way:** Remove backtick (``) from value and replace it with ('').

```
SELECT * FROM `data_specs` WHERE `Item_Code` = 'ACR102190250'
```

**Second Way:** Remove all backtick and just add ('') in the value

```
SELECT * FROM data_specs WHERE Item_Code = 'ACR102190250'
```

Comment: Using backsticks on the table name but not on the column name is not very consistent. Either use backsticks on both or don't but mixing syntax is just confusing.

Comment: You can do it many way. You can use or not. If you used to use backtick then what will be problem.